# fotorama breakpoints not working for nav

Tags: gallery, fotorama-slider

I have the breakpoint set to use dots for nav on mobile but they are not working. The nav stays as thumbs. Any suggestions?

```
<var name="breakpoints">
        <var name="mobile">
            <var name="conditions">
                <var name="max-width">767px</var>
            </var>
            <var name="options">
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="navigation">dots</var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>
```

Comment: this is completly HTML question

Comment: It is not an HTML question @MurtuzaZabuawala ! This is the xml file that sets the parameters for the fotorama extension used in Magento 2. This typo was found in the Magento written XML. Anyone on Magento 2 trying to use dots as navigation on mobile will need to fix this typo written by the Magento Team.

Answer (score -1):

So after digging I found a typo in view.xml. navigation in options should be "nav" instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/80513)

Comment: @liyakat I answered my own question to help others who may have the same issue. Why the down vote?!